# waiting on two processors in NIFI

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi

I have two NiFi flows, first one InvokeHTTP and insert the JSON reposnse in table1. Second one  InvokeHTTP and insert the JSON reposnse in table2. After table 1 and table2 is filled I am calling ExecuteSQL with a Select statement to select based on table1 and table2. I also need to insert an "id" from UpdateAttribute of one of the flow

I am following the approach as mentioned at https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-can-I-WAIT-on-two-processors-in-NIFI-Final-processor/td-p/158832

[image]

But, I am always getting this error

```
Unable to execute SQL select query Select  ...
due to The column index is out of range: 4, number of columns: 0.; routing to failure: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 4, number of columns: 0.
```

Also, if I directly connect GenerateFlowFile processor to ExecuteSQL it works fine and brings all the records from the table.

My properties for UpdateAttribute and MergeContent are:

[image]

Is this approach incorrect. Should I use wait notify.

Comment: I used wait-notify to solve this. But still don't know what is wrong with this aproach